# What type of regression analysis should be used for this combination of count data?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, proportion, poisson-regression, count-data

**What type of regression would be best suited to do a multiple regression analysis with $E$ as the dependent variable?** Is using a binomial regression okay? Thanks for any suggestion.

For each of my participants, I have 4 data point:

- score $A$: count between 0 and 10
- score $B$: count between 0 and 5
- score $C$: count between 0 and 15
- score $D$: count between 0 and 5

*I want to test the effet of several independent variables on the following dependent variable: $E$ = ($A$/10 + $B$/5 + $C$/15 + $D$/5) / 4*

If I needed to test the effect of these independent variable separately for each score $A$, $B$, $C$ or $D$, I would have no problem, because I could use multiple Poisson regression.

But for $E$, as you can see, this is not count data but this is not continuous: $E$ can take only a few values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Please don't create a new thread to improve [your previous question:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/620697/what-type-of-regression-is-best-suited-to-my-data?noredirect=1) just edit it.  Creating a new thread means you often will have to repeat part or all of the previous conversation with new people.

Comment: It might be worth observing that $E$ can take on $119$ distinct values pretty evenly distributed between $0$ and $1,$ indicating the issue really isn't whether it's discrete.  A more basic issue concerns the statistical nature of variation in $E$ conditional on the regressors.

Comment: Although the outcome in the question indicted as a duplicate only had 11 possible outcome levels, the principle extends to having as many outcome levels as there are observations. See Chapters 13 and 14 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/ordinal.html). For more information, search for "ordinal regression" on this site. Among the implementations that search will find, the `orm()` function in Harrell/s [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) has an implementation designed for large numbers of outcome levels.

Comment: But if, in my dataset, I do not have all the 119 values that $E$ can take, would an ordinal regression take into account the difference between two values? An example : imagine E can take the values 5%, 10%, 15%, ..., 100%, but I do not have an E = 10% in my dataset, would the ordinal regression take into account that E = 15% is two times better than E = 5% ? Or would it consider E = 15% as 1 time better than E = 5%, just like E = 20% is 1 time better than E = 15% ?

Comment: @EdM I am curious how one might apply ordinal regression to $E,$ given that its values are ordered only by virtue of assigning real numbers to the values of $A,\ldots, D.$ It also occurs to me that approaching this problem by first regressing the latter individually and then forming their linear combination to predict $E$ could be vastly inferior to regressing $E$ itself when there are negative associations among $A,\ldots,D.$ Perhaps a workable (but *ad hoc*) approach would be ordinal regressions of $A,\ldots,D$ to assign likely numerical values and combine them into an interval-valued $E.$

Comment: Taking the intervals between 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, $\dots$ in $E$  as identically spaced is a pretty strong assumption, given how $E$ is calculated. Ordinal regression makes no assumptions about the spacing. If you really think that there is even spacing, you could multiply your $E$ values by 120 (I think) to get into an integer scale, but a Poisson model might not be appropriate (even for $A$ through $D$ individually) as it assumes no limit to the number of counts.

Comment: @whuber the OP stated that the interest was in using $E$ as the outcome instead of multivariate $A, \dots ,D$. I assumed the OP had a good reason for forming $E$ in the way indicated; it's then ordinal, given the underlying (fairly strong) assumptions. I agree that other approaches might be better. Please feel free to remove the duplicate indication from this question if you think that it deserves specific attention from the CV audience beyond what's covered in the linked question.

Comment: @EdM The problem is that $E$ can attain far more values than 0, 0.05, ..., 1.00.  The problem is this: if we conceive of each of $A,\ldots,D$ as encoding latent values, say $\alpha_0$ through $\alpha_{10}$ for $A,$ *etc.*, each fully ranging from $0$ through $1,$ then the corresponding latent value of $E$ for a tuple $(A,B,C,D)=(a,b,c,d)$ (the original nominal values) is $\eta(a,b,c,d)=(\alpha_a+\beta_b+\gamma_c+\delta_d)/4.$ However, *the map from $e=(a/10+b/5+c/15+d/5)$ to $\eta$ does not necessarily preserve order.* I take it that $\eta$ is to be estimated.

Comment: Thanks to both of you @EdM and whuber for your comments. Maybe it will help if I explain what is counted in the each score $A$ through $D$. Each score is a number of correct answers given by the participant in a specific set of questions. To be honest, my statistical knowledge does not allow me to fully grasp some of your comments. But I understand that EdM would advice to use an ordinal regression analysis for $E$. EdM: would you also advice to use an ordinal regression for each score $A$ through $D$ individually, in case I needed to test effects of some explanatory variables on them too?

Comment: Consider starting with separate ordinal regressions of $A$ through $D,$ using models that estimate latent values for each category.  Then form the average of those estimated latent values ($\eta$) and regress that.  Along the way, draw a scatterplot of $\eta$ vs. $E:$ it ought to be interesting.  If it's monotonic (Spearman correlation is $1$) then conceivably an ordinal regression of $E$ would be worthwhile, especially if you have lots of observations.

Comment: Thanks @whuber for the suggestion. I'll try that!